# Django) How to connect urls-views-models in ManyToMany, OneToMany relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

I made some models which have ManyToMany, OneToMany relationships, and then I tried to make appropriate class in views.py, so that one can see sub models related to the chosen model.

But in terms of connecting models-serializers-views-urls, I just couldn't figure out how to make it work...

So, what I want to do is : (simplified)
There are 3 models.

1. Party
2. People
3. Food

[image: 스크린샷, 2019-04-30 13-41-40]

So `Party` has ManyToMany relationship with `People`, and OneToMany relationship with `Food`. When I reached url like `/party_id/people_id`, then I want to get specific person's information from given party id.

Here goes my code.

models.py

```
class Party(models.Model):
    par_id = models.TextField()
    par_people = models.ManyToManyField(People)

class People(models.Model):
    peo_id = models.TextField()
    peo_name = models.TextField()
    peo_type = models.TextField()

class Food(models.Model):
    foo_id = models.TextField()
    foo_party = models.ForeignKey(Party, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

serializers.py

```
class PartySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Party
        fields = ('par_id', 'par_people')
# People, Food has same structure...
```

views.py

```
class PartyList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Party.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PartySerializer
# People, Food has same structure...
```

urls.py

**Here's the part where I got lost**

```
#redundancy reduced...(e.g. import)
urlpatterns = [
    path('party/<int:par_id>/<int:peo_id>', views.PartyList.as_view()),
    path('party/<int:par_id>/<int:foo_id>', views.PartyList.as_view()),
]
```

So If I reach `website/party/1/3`, I want to see **person's information(whose peo_id is 3) of party(whose par_id is 1)**. For food, It goes the same.

Should I make new class in `views.py` to make it work? But how can url check `par_id` and `foo_id` at the same time if I use PartyList view class..? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: But you don't have a table with a person's specific information of a specific party.  For all parties where a person attends it is the same person information

Comment: Thanks for comment. I edited that line to clarify the issue. So what I want to know is how REST can get information from model(A) which belongs to another model(B) by accessing model(B).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this should work.  The basic principle if work out if using peo_id or foo_id and then filter the queryset on that basis.

```
def get (self, *args, **kwargs):
    id = kwargs.get(peo_id, None)
    if id:
        self.queryset.filter(par_people__peo_id=id)
    else:
        id = kwargs.get(foo_id, None)
        self.queryset.filter(foo_party=id)
```

Comment: You're my lifesaver :) I'll work more on the queryset!